# jQuery .click .animate to move down, then back up

Tags: jquery

So far I managed to make it so it moves down on a click in increments of 120, but I want it to go up and down, not down and down... I hope I've explained this so "someone" will understand.

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footertab').click(function() {
      $('#footer').animate({
        bottom: '-=120'
      }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Do you want it to move as a toggle or as in move down for 1 second then move back up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I get this right, you're looking to toggle the position of the footer. This can be done with the .toggle()-function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#footertab').toggle(function() {
    $('#footer').animate({
      bottom: '-=120'
    }, 1000);
  },function() {
    $('#footer').animate({
      bottom: '+=120'
    }, 1000);
  })
});
```

Comment: slight syntax error with your }, on line 10 }), works perfectly!

Comment: this use of `.toggle()` has been [deprecated/removed](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) since jQuery 1.8/1.9

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) for this:

```
$(function() { //shortcut for $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#footertab').toggle(function() {
    $('#footer').animate({ bottom: '-=120' }, 1000);
  }, function() {
    $('#footer').animate({ bottom: '+=120' }, 1000);
  });
});
```

By using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), every `click` event toggles between running the `-=` and `+=` animations.  Also note there's no need to include the animation callback if it doesn't do anything, just leave it off.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like slideToggle() http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footertab').toggle(
      function() {
        $('#footer').animate({
          bottom: '-=120'
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      },
      function() {
        $('#footer').animate({
          bottom: '+=120'
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      },
    );
  });
  </script>
```