# jQuery slide down toggle, impossible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a slide down with jQuery, but I can't find it anywhere.

I do **not** want it to [scale as it slides](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)
I do want it to perform [this action](http://see.weareinto.com/3tyP) ( click slide ), but vertically down, not horizontally right.

UPDATE :

So here's the final functional code!

```
$(this).toggle(
    "slide", 
    {
        direction: 'up',
        duration: 'slow',
        easing: 'easeOutQuart'
    }
);
```

Comment: slideDown doesn't scale as it slides. I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: Are you kidding me?? even the graphic on the documentation shows the scaling effect http://see.weareinto.com/3tTu

Comment: use: .animate({height: "toggle"}, 300);

Comment: @all - I really want to just use the jQuery UI slide function, but set *some* variable to animate from the top down. I can't fathom that this minor thing wouldn't be built into it somehow :\

Comment: @Grillz nope, that's the same as slideDown

Comment: Doesn't scale in any place I've used that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the API-Docs: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

You can Slide in every direction using the direction-option.

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/befbE/
(I set the width/height of the image inside the sliding element to 100%, so you can see, the image is not scaled, it's clipped, guess that's what you are looking for)

Comment: +1000! ah! just what I was looking for, obv is eluded everyone else too!

Comment: +1000 more for getting ridiculous and throwin' my pic up there, hahaha!

Comment: I still think it would be dope if it was a toggle chain function tho.. hmm

Answer (score 1):

If you position the element absolutely in a container and attach it to the bottom (ie. `position:absolute;bottom:0;`) you can use the blind effect and it will slide down to the bottom from the top. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UvxNd/)

Comment: This is looking really close! but how do I have it reveal/hide, and can it be as easy as maybe ".verticalSlideToggle()"

Answer (score 0):

If you want it the make own ur you, can you use `.animate()` and you using css.

something like:

css:

```
#elm { width: 150px; height: 80px; position: absolute; left: -150px; }
```

script:

```
// let it animate
$('#elm').animate({ display: 'block', left: 0 }, 'fast');
```

else if you dont wanna make it on your own, use that jQuery UI 'slide' effect?

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean - the items inside the DIV or whatever you are animating look like they are squahsed, and then expand.

Maybe consider hiding the element behind another and either move the masking element up and out of the way or slide the hidden element down using .animate()?

[jQuery .click .animate to move down, then back up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215789/jquery-click-animate-to-move-down-then-back-up)

This may help.

Comment: Thanks, but not elegant - I'm glad u know what I mean, ugh I don't understand how others don't see it sometimes :O

Comment: No its not perfect, you could look into developing your own methods for doing this in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with an inner container that has fixed dimentions.

[See this live example](http://jsfiddle.net/atvJp/). In the fiddle, the first `div` is without the inner container.

This way when the outer container animates (width/height) the inner container does not grow, simply *reveals*.

Comment: That looks like it grows from the corner :\

Comment: The theory is the same for all animations. I simply used a show which does width/height/opacity.

Comment: Sorry, but totally not my question

Answer (score 0):

**Consider** your **image** of **height 150px**

First apply **height="0"**

Use **animate** to achieve **slide down** effect

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo29.png" id="image_scale" width="200" height="0" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image_scale").animate({height:"150px"},"5000");
});
</script>
```

Comment: That is by definition SCALING :\ I want it to slide down, not scale down, please see question - Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely position the element you are wanting to slide in and out and use .animate() to change it's position.  You can have it slide in from the top, bottom, left, right, on the diagonal or however you want with this method.